# Recovering an ATtiny13

Tags: avr, programmer, fuse-bits

I am playing with an ATtiny13 and I thought it would be good to use it with an external 8Mhz ceramic oscillator instead of the 1.2 Mhz built-in one. (I want to do a soft-uart at 9600 bps, so I figured 1.2 Mhz was too slow)

To change to an external oscillator, I ran 'avrdude -c usbtiny -p attiny13 -U lfuse:w:0x70:m -U hfuse:w:0xff:m'

Unfortunately I can't access the device anymore now. The 'Blink the LED on PB0' program that was in there does not run anymore and the programmer can't connect to it.

Not sure what to do here. Can I throw away this chip or is there a way to rescue it?

Comment: What programmer are you using to write to the chip?

Comment: According the the avrdude command line it was a usbtiny.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean it was a usbtiny, it could be a clone.

Comment: Aren't Tiny13s like 80 cents?

Comment: @endo more like $1.95 when not buying in bulk T_T

Comment: Also, what good is another tiny if it just dies the same way?

*If you didn't fix it, it isn't fixed.*

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried to set the chip up with an external oscillator? Once the chip is programmed to use an external oscillator it will not work unless one is present. If you do not do this you will need [hi voltage programming](http://www.mightyohm.com/blog/2008/09/arduino-based-avr-high-voltage-programmer/) to reset the fuses.

Answer (score 7):

You should absolutely be able to recover it.  In the worst case, you might need a high voltage (12V?) programmer, though.

The fuse settings you used don't seem problematic to me.  Brown-out detect is off (that can be a gotcha) and SPI is enabled, so you should be able to reprogram it just fine.

The main thing is that it looks like you set it to need an external oscillator.  You were trying for that, so you probably have one around.  You need it hooked up in the system you're using for ISP programming, but that should be the only issue.

IOW, you're not doing anything weird.  It should all work.  Double-check that you don't have any problems in your setup.  Loose connections, that kind of thing.